# How do you append text in CodeMirror

Tags: codemirror

I know you use

```
editor.setValue("");
```

to set one value but how do you append in CodeMirror?

IE:

```
 editor.appendText();?
```

Comment: Something like `editor.setValue(editor.getValue() + "appended text")`?

Answer (score 16):

Use `replaceRange`. For example `editor.replaceRange(myString, CodeMirror.Pos(editor.lastLine()))`. Re-setting the entire editor is needlessly expensive.

---

Comment: Doesn't this just place the cursor at the last line, not the end of the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script I wrote to add code to any editor (in **Joomla**):

```
function addCodeToEditor(code_string, editor_id, merge, merge_target){
    if (Joomla.editors.instances.hasOwnProperty(editor_id)) {
        var old_code_string = Joomla.editors.instances[editor_id].getValue();
        if (merge && old_code_string.length > 0) {
            // make sure not to load the same string twice
            if (old_code_string.indexOf(code_string) == -1)  {
                if ('prepend' === merge_target) {
                    var _string = code_string + "\n\n" + old_code_string;
                } else if (merge_target && 'append' !== merge_target) {
                    var old_code_array = old_code_string.split(merge_target);
                    if (old_code_array.length > 1) {
                        var _string = old_code_array.shift() + "\n\n" + code_string + "\n\n" + merge_target + old_code_array.join(merge_target);
                    } else {
                        var _string = code_string + "\n\n" + merge_target + old_code_array.join('');
                    }
                } else {
                    var _string = old_code_string + "\n\n" + code_string;
                }
                Joomla.editors.instances[editor_id].setValue(_string.trim());
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            Joomla.editors.instances[editor_id].setValue(code_string.trim());
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        var old_code_string = jQuery('textarea#'+editor_id).val();
        if (merge && old_code_string.length > 0) {
            // make sure not to load the same string twice
            if (old_code_string.indexOf(code_string) == -1) {
                if ('prepend' === merge_target) {
                    var _string = code_string + "\n\n" + old_code_string;
                } else if (merge_target && 'append' !== merge_target) {
                    var old_code_array = old_code_string.split(merge_target);
                    if (old_code_array.length > 1) {
                        var _string = old_code_array.shift() + "\n\n" + code_string + "\n\n" + merge_target + old_code_array.join(merge_target);
                    } else {
                        var _string = code_string + "\n\n" + merge_target + old_code_array.join('');
                    }
                } else {
                    var _string = old_code_string + "\n\n" + code_string;
                }
                jQuery('textarea#'+editor_id).val(_string.trim());
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            jQuery('textarea#'+editor_id).val(code_string.trim());
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The advantage it this script is you can work with multiple editors on the page.